# Redirecting foreach output into a file

Tags: tcsh

The example below does not work: ~/test is empty.

```
foreach i (`ls`)
foreach echo $i > ~/test
foreach end
```

As well this does not work (unlike bash):

```
foreach i (`ls`)
foreach echo $i
foreach end > ~/test
```

Comment: Crossposted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491864/redirecting-foreach-output-into-a-file

Comment: Should it be deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is no way in tcsh to redirect the output of the whole foreach loop.
2. Workaround is to use addition '>>' on every turn of the loop, like this:

   ```
   foreach i (`ls`)
   echo $i >> ~/test    
   end
   ```

Comment: I don't understand what you were expecting as output of the single `foreach` line? `foreach` is putting the result of `ls` in the variable `i` (line by line), and as such there should be no output. And even if there was some output, you would be redirecting it, not copying it, so the `echo $i` would not print echo anything. This is not a "workaround", this is exactly how it should behave.

Comment: Cause, in bash you can put redirect at the end (after the word 'done') and it will redirect the output of the whole foreach loop